# Golang simultaneous read/write to the file without explicit file lock

Tags: go, io, synchronization

I have a situation where I need to concurrently read/write from/to the file, but the scope of operations is *limited*:

- append only, no random offset writes
- read from random position, where I know for sure the content has been written before(via append, internal access serialization via golang channel to ensure random read happens only after content's been appended)
- there is only one process running

This is a high loaded application and I would like to avoid locking file for each read/write I do

I was going to open 2 files - one for read, another for append only

would doing so create some potential issues/bugs?

what is the recommended practice if I would like to avoid file locking for each read/write I do?

p.s. golang, linux, ext4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll assume by "random read" you actually mean "arbitrary read".

If I understand your use case correctly, you don't need to seek or lock or do anything manual. UNIX has this covered via `O_APPEND`. Here is what you can do:

1. Open the file with [`os.O_APPEND`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#pkg-constants). This way every write, **regardless of any preceding operations**, will go to the end of the file
2. When reading use [`File.ReadAt`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.ReadAt). This lets you specify arbitrary offsets for your reads

Using this scheme you can avoid any sort of locking: the OS will do it for you. Because of the buffer cache this scheme is not even inefficient: appends and reads are pretty much independent.

Comment: are you sure there is no chance of data corruption? reads may happen in parallel with appends, the only guarantee I have is that read always done for the data that's been previously appended(in another goroutine) - this enforced with providing a "proper" offset for the read. Is there any official documentation you may link?

Comment: nice answer. I built and app that upload file to AWS (using io.Reader as input) but the data to be read comes in a stream generated by my upstream services in chunks of bytes. I thinking of this solution to write the streamed data into file and pass an io.Reader (which is a file reader of the same file) to aws file uploader.

Comment: Will this work for Windows too?